# Printing bytes of int in union C

Tags: c, integer, byte, union

How can I printf bytes of int when number 255 must be 255 not -1?
I can see that when I scanf 128 my program prints -128 but when I scanf 127 my program prints 127.
What can I do do printf 128 as 128.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    union byte_set{
    int x;
    char tab[4];
    };
    int main(){
         union byte_set byte_set;
        printf("Podaj liczbe: ");
        if(scanf("%d", &byte_set.x) != 1)
        {
            printf("Incorrect input");
            return 1;
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
        printf("%02d ", *(byte_set.tab+i));
        }
        return 0;
     }
```

Comment: It seems to be missing a `scanf` for the `tab`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the `tab` field to `unsigned char`.  Then they'll have the correct values.

```
union byte_set{
    int x;
    unsigned char tab[4];
};
```